# Why isn't my jQuery plugin loading in webkit browsers?

Tags: jquery, webkit, galleria

I'm using the Galleria plug-in. It works perfectly in Firefox and IE 7/8 but just completely fails in Chrome/Safari. The JavaScript doesn't even kick in, you can tell by the fact that it's not surrounded the #gallery div with the extra #galleria-container divs like it normally does. Literally nothing happens, I've checked the resource tracking, all the scripts are getting loaded in (obviously as well because it's working in IE/FF)

http://bit.ly/9GvxPj

Any help would be massively appreciated; I'm about to go insane.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, this might be causing issues:

```
<link href="js/classic/galleria.classic.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

It's hard to debug because I don't have control of the page, but Webkit may interpret that JavaScript you're including as CSS in some weird ways...I'm honestly not sure what the behavior is  in that case.

Comment: Not sure why it's calling it as CSS, I didn't notice that!

Comment: I'm not loading it in a CSS type, not sure why the debugger is showing that. The JS is getting called in an external JS script like this

Comment: Galleria.loadTheme('/js/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');

Comment: @Dan - I don't think you're following here, I'm not complaining about that line of JavaScript at all...I'm referring to the `<link>` element at the top of the page, the *only* code that's in my answer above...

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misread you, yeah that was a rouge tag in a PHP include I hadn't caught so thanks for that. Now that's gone it still doesn't load though!